# Oracle Weblogic 11g(10.3.6.0) doesn't show bundled JDKs

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, weblogic, weblogic11g

I am seeing this when try to install WLS 11g. Has anyone came across with this?Or any solution. At JDK selection pannel, I see nothing under bundled JDK section. I want to install jrockit with this.

Comment: Seems this is not available in generic download pack.But available in Win32 pack.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you got the generic jar installer - generic jar installer doesn't come with a JDK. When using the jar installer, you need to install the supported JDK/JRockit first then run the installer.

When you come to the JDK selection part, select the JAVA_HOME of your JDK/JRockit installation.

One thing I always tell people about weblogic installations: make sure whatever that the OS and JDK are certified by Oracle. You can verify here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/ias/downloads/fusion-certification-100350.html

Thanks,

Gavin | 
http://pitss.com/us